# Swift 2で、split()の使い方がわからない。ファイルパスの取り方がわからない。

Tags: swift

Xcode 7 beta5で、扱いが変わってしまったようです。
ちなみにiOSではなくOSX用に書いているソースです。

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
extension String : CollectionType {}

class ViewController: NSViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let filePath = paths[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("test01.txt")
    print (filePath)
    let data = htmlStringWithFilePath(filePath)

    data!.enumerateLines { (line, stop) -> () in
        print(line)
        print(split(line){ $0 == "\t"})
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

stringByAppendingPathComponentとsplitでエラーが出てしまいます。
XCODE7Bata4では上記のコードでできていたのですが・・・

わかる方、教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: ファイルパス取得は、**let filePath = paths[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("test01.txt")**
を、
    **let filePath = paths[0].stringByAppendingString("/test01.txt")**
に書き換えて、解決しました。


しかし、**split**関数が、うまくいきません。
引続き、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: **split**で出るエラーは、'split(_:maxSplit:allowEmptySlices:isSeparator:)' is unavailable: Use the split() method instead.です。